# How can I extract the background color of a tapped canvas?

Tags: c#, background, windows-store-apps, wpf-controls, winrt-xaml

I want to allow the user to select the color they want to use for the AppBar. I've got XAML like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Canvas Background="Aqua" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="CanvasColor_Tapped"></Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

...and this idea for the handler:

```
private void CanvasColor_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs treArgs)
{
    if (sender is Canvas)
    {
        Color colour = (Canvas) sender.Background;
    }

}
```

...but the compiler and my cranium are not cooperating / not on the same wavelength. Specifically, I get:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Background' and no extension method 'Background' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What need I to do to share an event handler among all the Canvas controls to extract the background color of the tapped canvas?

Comment: Did you try ((Canvas)sender).Background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing a pair of parenthesis.

```
Color colour = ((Canvas)sender).Background;
```

The compiler is looking for `Background` property in `sender` object which is of type `object`.

Comment: Close enough: What it had to be in actuality was:
Brush hueOfTheElectroMagneticSpectrum = ((Canvas)sender).Background;